# Does an underscore ever mean something special in regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I am trying to learn the basics of regular expressions and came across this in a [tutorial](http://regexrenamer.sourceforge.net/help/regex_quickref.html):

"\W Matches non-alphanumeric (same as [^a-zA-Z0-9_])"

What is the function of the underscore following 0-9 above?

From similar questions it seems it doesn't do anything. I just wanted to make sure this is a mistake in the tutorial. It seems odd they would include it.

This is not particular to any programming language.

Comment: It is a literal underscore; nothing special. The characters within a class `[   ]` can form a range if there is a hyphen between them, or just denote single characters, which is the case for the underscore in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underscore is not special in any regular expression language that I know of.

In this case, the regular expression would be appropriate for matching identifiers in some programming languages.  Identifiers may have underscores in a great many programming languages.  Indeed, `\w+` is commonly used to match identifiers.

Comment: In the cited tutorial it says \W mathes NON alphanumeric.  Then \W+ would be anything but identifiers.  Strange.

Comment: @DirkHerrmann I made a mistake in my answer, which I've corrected.  \w (lowercase) matches identifiers, \W (uppercase) matches _non_ identifiers, as the tutorial correctly notes.  Sorrya bout that.